# How can I create a ruby script to parse files uploaded by users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want users to be able to upload files and then I want to be able to parse them, taking out pieces of information and then declaring them as global variables to be used by other parts of my web application. I know you can easily put in a file upload form but then where would I store the script for parsing the file? Would it be under models, views, controllers, or somewhere else? Also how can I tell my application to immediately run this script upon the file upload. Would I put it in the view before the form's <% end %> tag? When it does parse the file, how can I make sure the variables (probably array's) are declared globally so that I can call those variables in all other parts of my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [EventMachine](http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/EventMachine.html#watch_class_method) you can watch a folder for file operations and then process them.
The Library [rb-inotify](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rb-inotify/0.8.8/frames) does fit aswell.

```
# Create the notifier
notifier = INotify::Notifier.new

# Run this callback whenever the file path/to/foo.txt is read
notifier.watch("path/to/foo.txt", :access) do
  puts "Foo.txt was accessed!"
end

# Watch for any file in the directory being deleted
# or moved out of the directory.
notifier.watch("path/to/directory", :delete, :moved_from) do |event|
  # The #name field of the event object contains the name of the affected file
  puts "#{event.name} is no longer in the directory!"
end

# Nothing happens until you run the notifier!
notifier.run
```

Comment: but what about once a file is created/uploaded. Is there a way to monitor that and then once it happens, process the file with some script stored elsewhere?

Comment: Yes you can do whatever you want whith files in he notifier.watch |block|